# Nodejs (with express npm) sending multiple data

Tags: javascript, express

I want to send multiple data in firebase realtime db using nodejs, express npm but single data is coming.

```
ref.on("value", snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
        var deger=snapshot.val();
        var notiKey = child.key;
        var notiVal = child.val();
        console.log(notiVal);

        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.send(notiVal);
        })
    })
   
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
    })
    
})
```

Console output of this code

```
{ body: 'testbody1', status: '1', title: 'test1' }
{ body: 'testbody2', status: '1', title: 'testtitle2' }
{ body: 'test3body', status: '1', title: 'testtitle3' }
{ body: 'bodytest5', status: '1', title: 'ester test 5' }
{ body: 'body6', status: '1', title: 'test6' }
{ body: 'Ester Deneme 3', status: '1', title: 'Deneme3' }
Example app listening on port 3000
```

output from localhost(127.0.0.1:3000)

```
{"body":"testbody1","status":"1","title":"test1"}
```

As you can see, it only receives the first data and other data does not come.

How can I send all data like console output?

Comment: You can only send a response once since the connection gets closed. So try appending all the results into an array and send it once the loop is done.

Comment: I recommend to start with the [Express tutorial](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). Currently, you are registering multiple request handlers for the same route in a loop. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Reyno 
I tried this but the result is still the same unfortunately

Comment: @jabaa
Since I'm using Firebase realtime db, I used it that way to get all the children of the data there.

Comment: Even with Firebase this construct doesn't make any sense. I recommend to go a step back and reread the basics. The loop belongs into the request handler and I guess `ref.on` also belongs into the request handler.